Flutter TTS in IOS16+ background
My TTS doesnt work on new iOS version (16+)
My app is developped on flutter, I need tts in background.
I try many configurations of tts but no result. I can share my code but I would Like to know if there is some known issue not yet fixed on this type of configuration…
Thx for your help
